# onbeforeunload in Chrome App?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-app, onbeforeunload

So apparently this is not supported. Is there a workaround or something?

Both `unload` and `beforeunload` only trigger when the window is loaded instead of unloaded so they are kind of useless.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with `unload` and `beforeunload` is that Chrome Apps are unloaded when they are idle and running code before an idle app is unloaded would make it not idle anymore. If you have data you need to save before your app is unloaded I suggest saving it when it is changed or after a short delay instead of waiting until your app exits.

Comment: What about a window from an iframe? I can manually unload it but the unload and beforeunload event still don't trigger.

Comment: You can register an event listener on the window you create with chrome.app.window.create so that your background page is notified when it closes: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window#method-create

Answer (score 0):

This may not be best practice, but this is working for me.

If you want to register an onClosed listener on an app window from the window itself rather than the background page, you can get a reference to the background page to use within your callback.

```
chrome.runtime.getBackgroundPage(function (backgroundPage){
  chrome.app.window.current().onClosed.addListener(function(){
    console.log("This won't appear anywhere since (this.)console doesn't exist anymore");
    backgroundPage.console.log("This will appear in the background page console, which you can open from the Extensions settings page");
  });
});
```

You can then use backgroundPage.chrome, backgroundPage.console etc to do any clearing up and show console logs for debugging. This was necessary for my particular case where I was using the chrome.hid API, and needed to send a stop command to a USB device when the app was closed.